# iOS Jump to next cell in UITableView when cell scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I would like to implement a UITableView with cells that are full screen.  When the user moves the cell up a portion, I would like to jump to the next cell as opposed to allowing it to scroll naturally.

I can't see a great deal of questions or answers out there on this, and perhaps it's because it's a daft idea, but the client wants to see it and the designer has designed it as such so I really must try.

Does anyone have ANY suggestions on how to implement this?

Thanks. (and thanks for pointing out my ignorance in not saying thanks!)

Comment: UITableView inherits from UIScrollView that has a property named pagingEnabled. Set that to YES and it should do what you want.

Comment: Like if the user scrolls up, the next cell is displayed?

Comment: Instead of rows, use sections then it will do the same automatically. You will require to update viewForSectionHeader which should look like a table cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your cells are going to be the same size as your tableView's height, set the `pagingEnabled` property to `YES`. This will make it snap to a full cell on each vertical swipe. I would ensure that the height is exactly full-screen if you do this, otherwise you'll end up with some weird offsets as you scroll.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // or somewhere similar
    self.tableView.pagingEnabled = YES;
}

...

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.tableView.frame.size.height;
}
```

It actually isn't a terrible idea- you could achieve similar functionality with a paging scroll-view, but this has the advantage of not needing to have all of your data loaded at once.

---

Edit: I also had to make sure to disable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on the controller, otherwise I had an undesired initial offset for the first cell, just in case you run in to that as well.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was looking to do.  I am having another problem with the first cell being offset slightly however, where do I disable automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets?

Comment: You can add the line `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in `viewDidLoad:`. Note that you set this on the actual controller and not on the table view.